# GIT What should I do - all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue"

Tags: git

When I run `git status` I see the following message which seems to be advicing me to run `git rebase --continue`.

I had a merge conflict yesterday, resolved it, merged it & pushed it to our staging site.

**UPDATE**
I ran `git rebase --skip` and it caused more problems!

```
$ (716-RWD) git status
On branch 716-RWD
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/716-RWD'.
You are currently rebasing branch '716-RWD' on '7e68797'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

nothing to commit, working directory clean
holy in ~/ubuntu_1404/httpdocs/magento
$ (716-RWD) git rebase --skip
Applying: themed product listings fro mobile
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
A   skin/frontend/bootstrapped/default/css/rwd.css
M   skin/frontend/bootstrapped/default/js/boutique.js
A   skin/frontend/bootstrapped/default/sass/_catalog-categories.scss
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
CONFLICT (modify/delete): skin/frontend/bootstrapped/default/sass/_catalog-categories.scss deleted in a2de9914584b4eae3b335700e9ef6486c858ab43 and modified in themed product listings fro mobile. Version themed product listings fro mobile of skin/frontend/bootstrapped/default/sass/_catalog-categories.scss left in tree.
CONFLICT (modify/delete): skin/frontend/bootstrapped/default/css/rwd.css deleted in a2de9914584b4eae3b335700e9ef6486c858ab43 and modified in themed product listings fro mobile. Version themed product listings fro mobile of skin/frontend/bootstrapped/default/css/rwd.css left in tree.
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0006 themed product listings fro mobile
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   /Users/holy/ubuntu_1404/httpdocs/magento/.git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".

holy in ~/ubuntu_1404/httpdocs/magento
$ (716-RWD) git status
On branch 716-RWD
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/716-RWD'.
You are currently rebasing branch '716-RWD' on '7e68797'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   app/design/frontend/bootstrapped/default/template/catalog/navigation/left.custom.phtml
    new file:   media/catalog/category/Booster.png

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

    deleted by us:   skin/frontend/bootstrapped/default/css/rwd.css
    deleted by us:   skin/frontend/bootstrapped/default/sass/_catalog-categories.scss
```

Comment: You can also do git rebase --abort

Comment: @Martin, I did `git rebase --skip` and it seemed to make more changes, not sure what to do now at all?  I updated my question with more details

Comment: @Holy First thing you need to do is read up on what rebasing is, and practice a little bit with a test repository. You are in the middle of an unfinished rebase. If you abort, it might undo any commits you have, but fortunately, `git reflog` keeps all commits so you can't lose anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Commit during Git Rebase - what really happens?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116572/git-commit-during-git-rebase-what-really-happens)

Answer (score 8):

In the end I ran `git rebase --abort` and then `git pull`.  Everthing is back to normal and all the changes I made on that branch seem to be there.

```
$ (716-RWD) git rebase --abort
ross in ~/ubuntu_1404/httpdocs/magento
$ (716-RWD) git status
On branch 716-RWD
Your branch is behind 'origin/716-RWD' by 7 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
ross in ~/ubuntu_1404/httpdocs/magento
$ (716-RWD) git pull
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues, try:

`git rebase --quit`

Comment: What is the advantage over *resolving the problem and running "git rebase --continue"*?